# How to preserve namespaces when parsing xml via ElementTree in Python while trying to modify xml

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I am trying to modify XML and writing the output to `output.xml`, but I'm not getting the desired output. In my XML, we have different namespaces:

1. Root namespace
2. Child namespace

I am able to preserve the root namespace using `register_namespace`, but I could not preserve the child namespace for `<genericSelection>` PSB.

Can someone please help me the way forward to achieve it.

Original file snippet:

```
<ptc:PricingObjectsJXB xmlns:ptc="http://xmlns.xyz.com/comm/platform/model">  
  <genericSelection xmlns:ptc="http://xmlns.xyz.com/comm/platform/model"></genericSelection>
</ptc:PricingObjectsJXB>
```

Output file snippet:

```
<ptc:PricingObjectsJXB xmlns:ptc="http://xmlns.xyz.com/comm/platform/model">  
  <genericSelection> missing namespace here</genericSelection>
</ptc:PricingObjectsJXB>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your original file and your saved file are equivalent. There is nothing you need to do.

```
<ptc:PricingObjectsJXB xmlns:ptc="http://xmlns.xyz.com/comm/platform/model">  
  <genericSelection xmlns:ptc="http://xmlns.xyz.com/comm/platform/model"></genericSelection>
</ptc:PricingObjectsJXB>
```

Here, only `<PricingObjectsJXB>` actually is in the `http://xmlns.xyz.com/comm/platform/model` namespace. `<genericSelection>` *declares* the `http://xmlns.xyz.com/comm/platform/model` namespace, but it is not actually in that namespace (otherwise it would also have the `ptc:` prefix).

Since the namespace is already declared at the parent, it's unnecessary to declare it again. The second namespace declaration is superfluous, and this is the same thing:

```
<ptc:PricingObjectsJXB xmlns:ptc="http://xmlns.xyz.com/comm/platform/model">  
  <genericSelection></genericSelection>
</ptc:PricingObjectsJXB>
```

This is what ElementTree gives you, and it's correct.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak for quick revert, I understand there is no need of namespace for generic selection but I want to achieve the same xml structure(in output.xml file) except few values under the hierarchy. Calling ET.write() method is deleting all the child namespaces which seems incorrect to me. How can I stop deleting it ?

Comment: If you absolutely have to preserve the second superfluous namespace declaration, use lxml instead of ElementTree.

Comment: @user3832730 The XML structure *is* the same. If you really understand that there is no need for the second declaration, you can't say that you would like to have the second declaration anyway.